# Ibatis SQL Query to check if Column exists in the table

Tags: sql, ibatis

What is the Ibatis SQL query to check if a column exists in the table. I tried the following but it gave an error:

```
<select id="getAllAccountsWithLastName" resultClass="com.replication.Account">
   if  exists(select * from Information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='UserName' AND column_name = 'LastName')
           begin
           EXEC('select Acc.Acc accountNumber,
                              Acc.AccName description,
                              Acc.Staff staff,
                              UserName.LastName lastName,
                              RiskProfile.ProfileDesc riskProfileDesc
                         from Acc
                         join UserName on (Acc.AccID = UserName.AccID)
                    left join RiskProfile on (Acc.RiskProfileID = RiskProfile.RiskProfileID)
                        where Acc.AccStat = ''A''')
           end
</select>
```

ERROR

```
    Invalid column name 'LastName'.
```

The same query works in SQL Server.